# How to update data in database using python 3.6 with GUI user inputs....?

Tags: python, oracle, python-3.6

This is my code but I'm getting an error which says that args are not defined.
I want to know how to access data from database and also from user in GUI.

```
def f6():

    upst.deiconify()
    root.withdraw()
    import cx_Oracle
    con=None
    cursor=None
    try:

        con=cx_Oracle.connect("system/abc123")
        cursor=con.cursor()
        sql="update student set name='%s' where rno='%d'"
        args(name,rno)
        cursor.execute(sql % args)
        con.commit()
        msg=str(cursor.rowcount)+"row updated"
        messagebox.showinfo("Record updated",msg)

    except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as e:
        if con is not None:
            con.rollback()
        messagebox.showerror("Failure",e)

    finally:
        cursor.close()
        if con is not None:
            con.close()

btnUpdate=Button(root,text="Update",width=10,command=f6)
```

Comment: `args(name,rno)` doesn't look right to me. If you want to create a variable named `args`, use assignment: `args = (name,rno)`.

Comment: thanx bro.. done with errors